# LinkedIn API return empty elements array

Tags: api, linkedin-api

Here is my request
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:6829881&sortBy=LAST_MODIFIED&sharesPerOwner=100&start=0&count=9

access_token is correct

Result looks like this:

```
  stdClass Object
(
    [paging] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start] => 0
            [count] => 9
            [links] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [type] => application/json
                            [rel] => next
                            [href] => /v2/shares?count=9&owners=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A6829881&q=owners&sharesPerOwner=100&sortBy=LAST_MODIFIED&start=0
                        )

                )

            [total] => 123
        )

    [elements] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Share API is legacy, the Post API will replace Share API [see August doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2022-08&tabs=http). I invite you to use `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/posts` to get all posts like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2022-08&tabs=http#find-posts-by-authors) and to retrieve some statics about share go [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/share-statistics?view=li-lms-2022-08&tabs=http#retrieve-statistics-for-specific-shares)

Comment: Are there any option to get posts only with article type of content?

also pagination isn't working   

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/posts?q=author&author=urn:li:organization:6829881&start=0&count=15
Url with params start=0 and count=15 return elemental array with 6 elements, but there are lot of posts